# Dark mode and light mode html, css, javascript how?

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes, darkmode

Hello and thank you in advance,
I would like to make a button with darkmode and if you click on it then it becomes darkmode and the button is then called white mode then when you click on it again it becomes white mode and the button is called dark mode again.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.page {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="page">Hello</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">dark mode</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.page;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to toggle the `dark-mode` class on `document.page`, which doesn't exist.

Instead, you should be toggling it on `document.body`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.page {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="page">Hello</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">dark mode</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

To only toggle the class on the `div`, use `querySelector`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.page {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="page">Hello</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">dark mode</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.querySelector('div.page');
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, but i have to turn a div box into dark mode on my online website and i found that on the internet but i didn't understand how it works for a div class.

Comment: @Kangoroo I've updated my answer.

Comment: I want to include this on my website but it doesn't work https://gecko.achmeindein.de (the website is in German) at the top left is the button

Comment: @Kangoroo You need to override the default `color` and `background-color`. Change your `.dark-mode` CSS to: `.dark-mode {
 background-color: #36393F !important;
 color: white !important;
}`.

Comment: how can i do the second page (.scrollseite2) and that if dark mode is the writing from the button to white mode

Comment: @Kangoroo Change your function to: `document.querySelectorAll('div.scrollseite,div.scrollseite2').forEach(e => e.classList.toggle('dark-mode'))`

Comment: and that if dark mode is the writing from the button to white mode

Comment: @Kangoroo What do you mean?

Comment: the button changes to "lightmode" when you click on it, so if the theme is dark the button is called lightmode and the lighttheme is called darkmode

Comment: @Kangoroo See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Spectric/ous5g860/

Comment: but I also want to edit css from the button if there is light mode

Comment: @Kangoroo It's pretty difficult for me to answer your questions in the comments. It would be much more easier if you could post another question so I can give you a more complete and helpful solution.

Comment: i have it i do it

Comment: i can only ask a new question in 90 minutes because i made a mistake

Comment: @Kangoroo The JS in the JsFiddle does change the CSS. What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
   if (element.classList.contains("dark-mode")){
    document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = "Light Mode";
   }
   else{
    document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = "Dark Mode";
   }
}
```

```css
.page {
  display:inline;
  background:#FFF;
  color: #121212;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.dark-mode,
.dark-mode .page {
  background-color:#202020;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">Hello</div>
<br><br><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="btn">Dark mode</button>
</body>
</html>
```